# making a leak proof thread for my keychain idea

Tags: threads

I have been designing a prototype for a keychain that sprays perfume. I have a metal keychain piece which has a female thread and the plastic sprayer screws right into it and has a male thread.

I want to get these manufacturers ASAP but I need to be ensured it wont leak. I think I will switch my straight thread to a tapered thread, will that help?

What can I do to ensure that it will not leak?

Thanks!!

Comment: wrap teflon thread sealing tape around the male part of the thread, screw the other part right over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tapered threads are intended to be leakproof, but the degree to which they resist leaks depends on how tightly they are screwed together. This generally requires the use of a tool of some sort, as it is usually not possible to tighten a tapered-thread joint enough by hand to make it stop leaking.

For this reason you should instead use straight threads and a gasket like a soft O-ring which is trapped between the two pieces when they are screwed together. Unlike the tapered thread joint, these can be tightened enough by hand to be leak-proof.